# Convert wide-form pandas DataFrame with hierarchical column index to tidy format

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to make a [seaborn facet plot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/many_facets.html) of a pandas dataframe with a heirarchical index. The first block of code generates something akin to the dataset I have to work with

```
from itertools import product, repeat
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dummy = np.random.random((4, 4))

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product('ab', 'cd')),
                                 names=['foo', 'bar'])
dat1 = DataFrame(dummy, columns=cols)
```

which looks like

```
foo         a                   b          
bar         c         d         c         d
0    0.266058  0.345076  0.339332  0.176753
1    0.094610  0.393542  0.838283  0.314625
2    0.598301  0.831869  0.277067  0.854321
3    0.910993  0.688163  0.158744  0.570700
```

and doesn't work with FacetGrid---at least, it's not in the form FacetGrid wants to work with. I can do some quick and dirty manipulations on the data

```
dfs  = [DataFrame([Series(dummy[:, i], name='obs'),
                   Series(list(repeat(cols.values[i][0], 4)), name='foo'),
                   Series(list(repeat(cols.values[i][1], 4)), name='bar')],).T
        for i in range(4)]
dat2 = pd.concat(dfs)
```

to get it to look like

```
         obs foo bar
0   0.266058   a   c
1  0.0946101   a   c
2   0.598301   a   c
3   0.910993   a   c
0   0.345076   a   d
1   0.393542   a   d
2   0.831869   a   d
3   0.688163   a   d
0   0.339332   b   c
1   0.838283   b   c
2   0.277067   b   c
3   0.158744   b   c
0   0.176753   b   d
1   0.314625   b   d
2   0.854321   b   d
3     0.5707   b   d
```

which looks like the data from the [seaborn example gallery](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/many_facets.html). My question is, is there a DataFrame or Index method to finagle this kind of transformation for me. It seems like it should exist, but I've not yet found it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
dat1.unstack().reset_index(["foo", "bar"], name="obs")


  foo bar       obs
0   a   c  0.716688
1   a   c  0.945587
2   a   c  0.388928
3   a   c  0.597745
0   a   d  0.201622
1   a   d  0.267941
2   a   d  0.575878
3   a   d  0.632626
0   b   c  0.143869
1   b   c  0.499576
2   b   c  0.860764
3   b   c  0.369183
0   b   d  0.857490
1   b   d  0.048870
2   b   d  0.804838
3   b   d  0.230868
```